# Magento 2 - bin/magento No commands working - Class 'Cli' not found Error

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cli' not found in
>   /home/xxx-xxx/public_html/bin/magento on line 31

```
xxx-xxx@rck:~/public_html$ php bin/magento
```

No lock file found. Unable to read locked packages#0

> /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php(146):
>   Composer\Package\Locker->getLockData()
>
> Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')

I am trying following commands:

```
php bin/magento

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: specify complete command which you try to run from Command line.

Comment: I have updated the question, Kindly read again. Thanks!

Comment: just try only this command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Comment: Already tried, No Luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the composer.lock file and you must run the commands:

```
composer update
```

After you ran the above command, you can run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: There was missing composer.lock and composer.phar file!
I have uploaded both and DONE!!

Comment: Your welcome. :)